# Product form of a Dirichlet convolution

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-convolution

I have derived (by a little unpure way) the product form for a Dirichlet convolution
$$f*g\left(n\right)=\sum_{d|n}f\left(d\right)g\left(\frac nd \right)=\prod_{p|n} \left( \sum_{m=0}^{k_p} f \left( p^m \right)g\left(p^{k_p -m}\right) \right)$$
where $f$ and $g$ are multiplicative functions, $p$ is a prime and
$$n=\prod_{p|n}p^{k_p} .$$
The product forms for the multiplicative function $f$ are
$$F\left( n \right) =\sum_{d|n}f\left(d\right)=\prod_{p|n}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{k_p} f \left( p^m \right) \right)$$
and
$$f\left( n \right) = \prod_{p|n} \left( F\left(p^{k_p} \right)-F\left(p^{k_{p}-1} \right)\right) $$
I get the correct result for all multiplicative function I know, but I am not able to prove it generally. Could someone to help me?

Comment: A standard approach (that works well very often) when dealing with multiplicative functions is to first prove things for prime powers. (Provided you have already proved, by some means, that $f * g$ is also multiplicative.)

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but I don't know, it the right side is a multiplicative functions too, because sum of multiplicative functions is not generally multiplicative.

Comment: What does $f * g(p^k)$ look like by definition? Work that out, then evaluate $f * g(n)$ using multiplicativity.

Comment: $f*g\left(n\right)=\sum_{d|n}f\left(d\right)g\left(\frac nd \right)$ by definition.

Comment: And if $n = p^k$ is a prime power, it simplifies to..?

Comment: $\sum_{l=0}^k f\left( p^l\right) g \left( p^{k-l} \right) $

Comment: Yes indeed, and distinct prime powers are relatively prime, proving your identity. (Notice how that is the inner sum in your right-hand side.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Dirichlet convolution of multiplicative functions is multiplicative, we only need to understand $(f * g)(p^k)$ where $p$ is prime and $k \geq 0$.
In particular,
$$  (f * g)(p^k) = \sum_{d \mid p^k} f(d) g(p^k / d) = \sum_{m = 0}^k f(p^m) g(p^{k - m}) $$
since the only divisors of a prime power are powers of the same prime.

Now by multiplicativity, if $n = \prod p^{k_p}$, we have
$$ (f * g)(n) = \prod_{p \mid n} (f * g)(p^{k_p}) = \prod_{p \mid n} \sum_{m = 0}^{k_p} f(p^m) g(p^{k_p - m}) $$
since powers of distinct primes are relatively prime.

Comment: The step $$\left( f*g \right) \left( \prod_{p|n}p^{k_p} \right) = \prod_{p|n}\left(f*g\right)\left(  p^{k_p} \right) $$ is to quick for me ...

Comment: If a function $h$ is multiplicative, then $h(a b) = h(a) h(b)$ for $\gcd(a, b) = 1$. The above is the same property where $a = p^k$ and $b = q^l$ for primes $p \neq k$ and $h = f * g$.

Comment: OK, thank you very much.

Comment: (The previous comment should say "primes $p \neq q$", sorry about that typo.)

Comment: No problem, the sense was clear.